# how to partition the data with specific row size

Tags: r, matrix, split

Say I have the following matrix:

```
X = matrix(rnorm(4000), nrow=400, ncol=10)
size = c(80,80,79,80,81)
```

I want to partition the matrix row-wise according to the above size in a concise way. To illustrate,

```
x1 = X[1:80,]
x2 = X[81:160,]
.
.
x5 = X[320:400,]
```

I usually have different sizes and different matrices, so I won't be able to do this manually every time. Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below

```
e <- cumsum(size)
b <- c(1, head(e + 1, -1))
out <- Map(function(rb, re) X[rb:re, ], b, e)
```

and you will see

```
> str(out)
List of 5
 $ : num [1:80, 1:10] 0.253 -0.368 0.804 -0.603 -0.119 ...
 $ : num [1:80, 1:10] 0.467 -0.743 -0.401 1.48 0.853 ...
 $ : num [1:79, 1:10] -1.123 -0.873 -1.039 -0.247 -0.774 ...
 $ : num [1:80, 1:10] -1.409 -0.683 -0.514 0.485 -0.347 ...
 $ : num [1:81, 1:10] 0.58 0.529 -0.803 0.49 -0.847 ...
```

---

Furthermore, if you want to create variables, try

```
list2env(setNames(out,paste0("x",seq_along(out))),envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get start and end points using `cumsum` and use `Map` to subset them and create list of matrices.

```
X = matrix(rnorm(4000), nrow=400, ncol=10)
size = c(80,80,79,80,81)

val <- cumsum(size)
result <- Map(function(x, y) X[x:y, ], c(1, val[-length(val)] + 1), val)
```

where `c(1, val[-length(val)] + 1)` creates the starting row numbers and `val` are the ending ones.

```
c(1, val[-length(val)] + 1)
#[1]   1  81 161 240 320

val
#[1]  80 160 239 319 400
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map2`

```
library(purrr)
size1 <- cumsum(size)
map2(size1, c(1, size1[-length(size1)] + 1), ~ X[.x:.y,])
```